# How to select a polygon by click its internal space

Tags: openlayers

I make a `Select` like the openlayers example:

```js
this.select = new Select()
this.map.addInteraction(this.select)
this.selectedFeatures = this.select.getFeatures()
```

But I can only select polygon at its boundary. How can I select the polygon when clicking at the internal space?

Comment: The polygon must be styled with a fill.  You use `color: 'transparent'` if you do not want the fill to be visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Select](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_interaction_Select-Select.html):

> style Style for the selected features. By default the default edit style is used (see module:ol/style).

The default edit style only "highlights" broundaries, but you can create a different style:

```
this.select = new Select({
    style: new Style({
        fill: new Fill({
            color: [0, 0, 255, 0.5]
        })
    })
});
this.map.addInteraction(this.select);
```

Here is a working demo:

https://anatolysukhanov.com/stackoverflow/openlayers/4-select.html

Comment: That helps a lot! Thanks!